Surreal numbers: the day $\omega$ was created.
I've been reading the absolutely great "Surreal Numbers" by Knuth, but I've been stuck on the $\aleph$ day problem (apologies for not using the right symbol: the right symbol is \aleph). Alice and Bob (pretty great mathematicians) are discussing the $\aleph$ day on page 94 of the book.
What I do understand is that on the $\aleph$ day, all real numbers are been created: Bill says

... when it says the universe was created on $\aleph$ day: The real numbers are the universe.

Now, from previous chapters and how numbers like $1$, $-1$, etc. have been created, they've always needed numbers from the previous days in $X_L$ or $X_R$.
What I'm struggling to understand, however, is how $\omega$, (or $\epsilon$, for that matter), gets created on this day, when $\omega$ is also not in the real number system, and is greater than all real numbers. Wouldn't it require all the reals in $X_L$ to be greater than the reals themselves? (And hence require the reals to have been created on a previous day?)

$\omega = {0,1,2,3,\ldots| }$. And all those elements are created in a finite day, so by the day $\omega$ all its left members are already created.

@jjagmath I think you could post that verbatim as an answer.

"the day" is a strange formulation. $\omega$ is simply defined to be the set of the naturnal numbers which can be captured in ZFC , but not in PA.  Also, what is already clarified in the comments needs not an answer anymore. It is against the spirit of this site to answer questions having a "one-line answer".

@Peter Talking about "the day a number is born" is the common usage when talking about surreal numbers that comes from the books of Conway and Knuth.

@MarkS. I agree with Peter, "one-line answer" are better as comments.

@MarkS. is was the \aleph symbol (edited my text in case someone else struggles to find it).
@jjagmath I'm not sure I totally understand: the book talks about all the real numbers being created on $\aleph$ day. So it follows that to be able to use these numbers in $X_L$, we must need to wait until $\aleph + 1$, right?

@Ashesh "all the real numbers being created on $\aleph$ day." That's obviously false. $0$ is a real number and is created in the $0$-th day, $1$ is created in the day $1$.

@Ashesh You should say: MOST real numbers are created on the day $\omega$, but $\omega$ itself is also created in the $\omega$ day, because you don't need all the real numbers in order to construct ${0,1,2,3,\ldots| }$

@jjagmath Leaving the answer as ephemeral comments means that this question stays on the list of unanswered questions, and that your comments which address the question are possibly less permanent/accessible, to boot. If your comments have addressed Ashesh's question, and you do not wish to post an answer, I would recommend Ashesh post one (and would consider writing your comments as a community wiki answer myself).

As @jjagmath commented,

$\omega = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots| \}$. And all those elements are created in a finite day, so by the day $\omega$ all its left members are already created.

Each surreal number in $X_L$ is less than each surreal number in $X_R$, trivially in this case since $X_R$ is empty here.
Note that what Knuth wrote as $\aleph$ would be written as $\omega$ by Conway in On Numbers and Games, since it fits with the class of surreal numbers including all ordinals. We can say a little more:

each integer is created on a finite day
each dyadic rational (with denominator a power of $2$) is created on a finite day
all the other rationals and reals are created on day $\omega$,

for example $\frac13 = \{0,\frac14, \frac5{16}, \frac{21}{64}, \ldots | 1, \frac12, \frac38, \frac{11}{32}, \ldots\}$


some other numbers created on day $\omega$ are:

$\omega = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots| \}$
$-\omega = \{|0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots \}$
$\epsilon = \{0 | 1,\frac12, \frac14, \frac18, \ldots \}$


more surreal numbers are created the next day $\omega +1$, including

$\omega +1 = \{\omega| \}$
$\omega - 1 = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots| \omega\}$
$\frac\epsilon2 = \{0 | \epsilon \}$


and many more in later days, so many that the surreal numbers make up a proper class rather than a set.


Just curious: what is ${|\omega}$? $\omega-1$?

@Anixx No: ${|\omega}=0$ and ${-\omega|\omega}=0$ while ${0|\omega}=1$.  In general  ${X_L|X_R}$ is the surreal number with the earliest birthday that is greater than all the elements of $X_L$ and less than all the elements of $X_R$, and you can prove that there is only one such surreal number (if there were two with a given birthday, then there would be another between them with an earlier birthday).

Thanks you!....
